# Estimator of The Mean of the Ratio of Uniformly Distributed Variables

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution, estimators

Given two random variables, $ X \sim U \left[ {\mu}_{x} - \frac{{l}_{x}}{2} > 0,  {\mu}_{x} + \frac{{l}_{x}}{2} \right] $ and $ Y \sim U \left[ {\mu}_{y} - \frac{{l}_{y}}{2} > 0,  {\mu}_{y} + \frac{{l}_{y}}{2} \right] $ which are independent.
The parameters $ {l}_{x}, {l}_{y} $ which are the length of the support of each RV are known.
The mean (Center of the support), $ {\mu}_{x}, {\mu}_{y} $, of them isn't known.

I am after the Maximum Likelihood Estimator or any other reasonable estimator for the mean of the ratio $ \frac{X}{Y} $, namely $ E \left[ \frac{X}{Y} \right] $ given $ N $ measurements of $ X $ and $ Y $.

What if the two are correlated with correlation factor $ E \left[ X Y \right] = \rho $ what would be then the case?

I'd love any of you intuition for the problem.
It is related to the following question:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22738/estimation-of-hit-time-using-kalman

Thank You.

Comment: Doesn't the PS imply your question makes no sense?  It seems to be telling us, "I know that the mean of $X/Y$ does not exist, so what is its maximum likelihood estimator?"

Comment: Because once you have samples you might say something about it. Let's say both $ \frac{ \left | x - {\mu}_{x} \right | }{{\sigma}_{x}} \gg 0 $. Moreover, each sample we also obeys this property.

Comment: @whuber, For the sake of the argument, I replaced the distribution to be uniform.

Comment: @whuber, is there any solution in the case of Uniform Distribution?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of your notation.  Of the four parameters $a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y$, which do you know and which need to be estimated? Regardless, MLEs based on data for $X$ and $Y$ will give you all four numbers from which the expectation of $X/Y$ is easily derived. In the second case, $\rho$ is not sufficient to define a parametric bivariate family (there are just too many bivariate distributions with uniform marginals and correlation $\rho$), so it would be difficult to obtain any kind of MLE without making substantial additional assumptions.

Comment: @whuber, I updated the question. All parameters are known. Could you please write your knowledge? It will be great assist. Thank You.